# Custom bottom navbar flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to create a custom bottom navigation bar, similar to the one shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

Could you please provide guidance on how to achieve this? I am interested in customizing the appearance and functionality of the bottom navigation bar in my application. Any tips, code snippets, or recommended resources would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

**Edit** :

[image]

The result i have with the code below

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Custom Bottom Navigation Bar'),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Text('Page ${_currentIndex + 1}'),
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        child: Container(
          height: 60.0,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _currentIndex = 0;
                  });
                },
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _currentIndex = 1;
                  });
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 80.0), // Espace réservé pour l'icône SVG
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _currentIndex = 2;
                  });
                },
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _currentIndex = 3;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: -40.0,
        left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 24.0,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/rugby.svg', // Remplacez par le chemin de votre fichier SVG
              height: 80.0,
              width: 80.0,
            ),
            Text('Icône', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: You can use row with tappable widget as navItem, you can also use Stack(BackGorund,Buttons...)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh i edited my question but look at the result i have..

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to build Bottom navigation bar in flutter, First let me list down some flutter packages that I have used for bottom navigations

1. `animated_bottom_navigation_bar: ^1.2.0` (provides a lot of customisation; P.S., I love this one)
2. `circular_bottom_navigation: ^2.3.0`
3. `bottom_navigation_view: ^0.3.0`
4. `curved_navigation_bar: ^1.0.3` (I have used this one recently, I provides beautiful curved animation, have customised it code to achieve shadows and other stuff)

Before using any package for bottom navigation always review other packages as well.

Now if don't want to use any package bellow is the code snippet to build button navigation bar in Flutter

There is property named `buttomNavigationBar` in Sraffold!

```
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
    clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      color: AppColors.white,
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: AppColors.lightGrayColor,
          spreadRadius: 2,
          blurRadius: 7,
          offset: Offset(2, 2),
        ),
      ],
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
        topRight: Radius.circular(20),
      ),
    ),
    child: BottomNavigationBar(
      currentIndex: viewModel.currentIndex,
      selectedItemColor: AppColors.lightPrimaryColor,
      unselectedItemColor: AppColors.textColor,
      onTap: viewModel.onTap,
      selectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(color: AppColors.lightPrimaryColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(color: AppColors.textColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      elevation: 0,
      items: const [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          label: 'Home',
          icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
          activeIcon: Icon(Icons.home)
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          label: 'Categories',
          icon: Icon(Icons.category_outlined),
          activeIcon: Icon(Icons.category)
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          label: 'Cart',
          icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_outlined),
          activeIcon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart)
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, the fact is that i want to create a new component to make it like the 1st screen. I edited my question for more precisions.
And i would like to not use any externe libraries ...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [NavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationBar-class.html) which is the version that follows the recommendations of [Material 3](https://m3.material.io/). In this case you should modify certain things to specifically achieve that aspect you could modify: splashColor, hoverColor and indicatorColor.
You could use a `StatefullWidget` to modify or perform some animation, be it resize, rotate or whatever you need: to do this you should basically update the selectedIndex through `setState` and in combination with some [AnimatedFoo](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget-class.html) widget to achieve a nice effect.

If your requirements are very specific you can always build the button bar with a simple Row and customize it the way you want.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, the fact is that i want to create a new component to make it like the 1st screen. I edited my question for more precisions